# Which ASP.NET Server controls have Auto Postback set to TRUE by default

Tags: asp.net

I presume only the Button server control in ASP.NET has AUTO POST BACK set to TRUE by default. All others need explicit setting of this property on need basis. Am i right ?

Thanks,
Chakra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All except, Buttons, Hyperlinks and LinkButtons have a default Auto Post Back property of false in the stock ASP.NET control library.

Other controls that have the same expected behavior as a button fall into this category as well.  So the DataPager controls, etc. would as well.  Those controls behavior are essential just that of a button only.  Other controls that have more than a singular use will have to have the auto post back enabled.